# View, выбирающий похожие данные из нескольких таблиц, разделенных по типу

Tags: sql, sql-server, инспекция-кода

У меня есть несколько таблиц, реализующих схему БД некоторой CMS:

- `cms.CatalogEntry` обозначает любую (всех типов) запись в каталоге.
- `cms.CatalogEntryType` описывает тип сущности (Artist/Genre/Release/Product/другой), связан с первой с помощью внешнего ключа `CatalogEntryTypeId` в ней.
- `dbo.Artist` для полей, специфичных для исполнителя (`Name`, `Description`).
- `dbo.Release` для полей, специфичных для музыкального релиза (`Title`, `Description`, `CatalogNumber`).
- Несколько других таблиц, практически повторяющих две последние. Каждая из подобных таблиц имеет свой собственный `Id` и связывается через `CatalogEntryId` с упомянутой выше `cms.CatalogEntry.Id`.

Теперь мне нужно создать `View`, который возвращал бы мне пары (`EntityId`, `CatalogEntryId`), где `EntityId` может быть любым из ключей таблиц-расширений `dbo.Artist.Id`/`dbo.Release.Id`/другим, а также некоторую другую общую информацию (тип и `DisplayName`). У меня есть две основные идеи, как это можно реализовать:

Первая идея - собрать через `LEFT JOIN` все (~15) типизированные по сущностям таблицы расширений и потом использовать `COALESCE`, чтобы выбрать колонку, значение из которой использовать.

```
CREATE VIEW [cms].[CatalogEntryToEntityMap]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    [catalogEntry].[Id] AS [CatalogEntryId],
    [catalogEntry].[CatalogEntryTypeId] AS [CatalogEntryTypeId],
    COALESCE(
        [genre].[Id],
        [artist].[Id],
        N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') AS [EntityId],
    COALESCE(
        [genre].[Name],
        [artist].[Name],
        N'N/A') AS [EntityDisplayName]
FROM [cms].[CatalogEntry] AS [catalogEntry]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Genre] AS [genre] ON [genre].[CatalogEntryId] = [catalogEntry].[Id]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Artist] AS [artist] ON [artist].[CatalogEntryId] = [catalogEntry].[Id];
```

[image: 1st plan]

Вторая идея - использовать `UNION ALL`, чтобы собрать конечный результат из типизированных по сущности подмножеств:

```
CREATE VIEW [cms].[CatalogEntryToEntityMap]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    [genre].[Id] AS [EntityId],
    [genre].[CatalogEntryId],
    [genre].[Name] AS [EntityDisplayName],
    [catalogEntry].[CatalogEntryTypeId]
FROM [dbo].[Genre] AS [genre]
INNER JOIN [cms].[CatalogEntry] AS [catalogEntry]
    ON [catalogEntry].[Id] = [genre].[CatalogEntryId]
    AND [catalogEntry].[CatalogEntryTypeId] = N'DEVELOPMENT-TIME KNOWN GUID'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    [artist].[Id] AS [EntityId],
    [artist].[CatalogEntryId],
    [artist].[Name] AS [EntityDisplayName],
    [catalogEntry].[CatalogEntryTypeId]
FROM [dbo].[Artist] AS [artist]
INNER JOIN [cms].[CatalogEntry] AS [catalogEntry]
    ON [catalogEntry].[Id] = [artist].[CatalogEntryId]
    AND [catalogEntry].[CatalogEntryTypeId] = N'ANOTHER DEVELOPMENT-TIME KNOWN GUID';
```

[image: 2nd plan]

Или по-другому:

```
CREATE VIEW [cms].[CatalogEntryToEntityMap]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    [entity].[Id] AS [EntityId],
    [entity].[DisplayName] AS [EntityDisplayName],
    [catalogEntry].[Id] AS [CatalogEntryId],
    [catalogEntry].[CatalogEntryTypeId] AS [CatalogEntryTypeId]
FROM [cms].[CatalogEntry] AS [catalogEntry]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [genre].[Id], [genre].[CatalogEntryId], [genre].[Name] AS [DisplayName] FROM [dbo].[Genre] AS [genre]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [artist].[Id], [artist].[CatalogEntryId], [artist].[Name] AS [DisplayName] FROM [dbo].[Artist] AS [artist]
)
AS [entity] ON [entity].[CatalogEntryId] = [catalogEntry].[Id];
```

[image: 3rd plan]

Я посмотрел на планы исполнения для всех трех, в последних двух вроде бы нет каких-то очевидных подвохов, почти все происходит через индексы на базовых таблицах. В первом плане есть сомнения по поводу повторяющихся джоинов, но тут, вроде бы, ничего не поделать.

Меня немного беспокоит, что я не могу создатть индексы ни на одном из трех (на первом из-за `LEFT JOIN` и на вторых из-за `UNION ALL` и вложенных селектов), количество данных может быть довольно большим, и мне придется делать запросы к этому `VIEW` на регулярной основе практически на каждом GET-запросе сущности из каталога. Я не планирую писать какие-то сложные селекты, основаные на этом представлении, но я должен иметь возможность `INNER JOIN`-ить его на множества ключей (`CatalogEntryId` и `EntityId`), по которым мне нужны пары.

Видит ли кто-то какие-то дополнительные проблемы с представленными решениями? Меня по большей части интересует производительность.

Я также открыт к другим решениям, если кому-то придет в голову способ сделать это эффективнее.

[P.S. Перевод моего вопроса c англоязычного SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77708669/view-selecting-from-multiple-similar-type-specific-tables)

Comment: Если я правильно понял, тут реализовано наследование (inheritance)? Его можно реализовать в РСУБД тремя способами, которые в Entity Framework называют TPH, TPT, TPC. Если знакомы с EF, то гляньте документацию, там хорошо расписаны достоинства и недостатки каждого из них. А вот описание реализации в чистом SQL сходу не могу найти.

Comment: Тут таблица на тип (table per type - TPT). Требуется много джойнов, как итог - низкая производительность. В EF по умолчанию используется таблица на иерархию (table per hierarchy - TPH). Его производительность в большинстве случаев выше (естественно, не всегда). Не нужно много джойнов; для указания типа используется поле-дискриминатор в таблице.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да, это попытка в наследование на РСУБД. Используется Entity Framework Core, почитаю про перечисленные типы, спасибо.

Comment: [Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance), [Modeling for Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/modeling-for-performance#inheritance-mapping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сомневаюсь, что кто-то за меня напишет полноценный ответ, поэтому...

В конечном итоге остановился на варианте 3:

```
CREATE VIEW [cms].[CatalogEntryToEntityMap]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
    [entity].[Id] AS [EntityId],
    [entity].[DisplayName] AS [EntityDisplayName],
    [catalogEntry].[Id] AS [CatalogEntryId],
    [catalogEntry].[CatalogEntryTypeId] AS [CatalogEntryTypeId]
FROM [cms].[CatalogEntry] AS [catalogEntry]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT [genre].[Id], [genre].[CatalogEntryId], [genre].[Name] AS [DisplayName] FROM [dbo].[Genre] AS [genre]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [artist].[Id], [artist].[CatalogEntryId], [artist].[Name] AS [DisplayName] FROM [dbo].[Artist] AS [artist]
)
AS [entity] ON [entity].[CatalogEntryId] = [catalogEntry].[Id];
```

В плане, сгенерированном для него, отсутствуют повторяющиеся `LEFT JOIN`-ы, как в первом, и при этом он более лаконичный, чем второй.

Для тестирования создал 3 типа сущностей, заполнив таблицы тестовыми данными по 100к записей в каждой.

Фактический план выполнения запроса, выгребающего все представление:

```
SELECT * FROM [cms].[CatalogEntryToEntityMap];
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То же самое, но с дополнительной фильтрацией через `INNER JOIN` на список `CatalogEntryId`:

```
DECLARE @CatalogEntryIds AS [dbo].[GuidArray];

INSERT INTO @CatalogEntryIds ([Value])
SELECT [Id]
FROM [cms].[CatalogEntry]
WHERE [Id] LIKE N'00%'; -- Все GUID-ы, начинающиеся с 00

SELECT *
FROM [cms].[CatalogEntryToEntityMap] AS [map]
INNER JOIN @CatalogEntryIds AS [id] ON [id].[Value] = [map].[CatalogEntryId];
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить, предварительная фильтрация для уменьшения объема данных применяется как на `cms.CatalogEntry`, так и на присоединяемых `dbo.Artist/Genre/Release`. Также видно, что везде применяются индексы используемых для формирования представления таблиц, полных сканов таблиц не происходит.

Отдельно хочу выразить благодарность **@AlexanderPetrov** за ссылку на реализацию наследования средствами EF Core. В версии 6.x доступны только маппинги `Table Per Hierarchy` и `Table Per Type`, оба из которых мне не очень подходили, поскольку первый превращает таблицу в "мусорку" из всего возможного для иерархии сущностей набора полей, а второй имеет страдающую производительность. В версии 7.x также появилась `Table Per Concrete type`, которая должна генерировать схему БД, примерно схожую с моей.